# Add to cart button only on one simple product

Tags: woocommerce

i would like to show add to cart button only on one simple product.

I have two sort of products :
- variation product with only a "Request quote" button > i have hidden add to cart
- simple product with only "add to cart" button > i have hidden request quote button

But a new product requires both buttons.

This part of code hide quote button and works :

```
if( !function_exists( 'ywraq_hide_quote_for_simple_products' ) ){
    add_filter( 'yith_ywraq_before_print_button', 'ywraq_hide_quote_for_simple_products', 10, 2 );
    /**
     * @param bool $show
     * @param WC_Product $product
     * @return bool
     **/
    function ywraq_hide_quote_for_simple_products( $show, $product ){

        if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
            $show = false;
        }

        return $show;
    }
}
```

on code above i try to add the code below to show both buttons, don't work :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'onlyonesimpleproduct_is_purchasable', 10, 2);

function onlyonesimpleproduct_is_purchasable( $is_purchasable, $object ) {
    // Checks to see if the product id is 135, 
    // returns true if is, false otherwise.  
    return ( 135 === $object->id );
}
```

and this part hide add to cart and works :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hide_add_to_cart_button_variable_product', 1, 0 );
function hide_add_to_cart_button_variable_product() {

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
}
```

Could you help me to implemente the second part of code inside the first part ? Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few tries i found a solution who works for me, remember I first wanted to display two buttons "add to cart" and "ask for a quote", but I hid one or the other with the code above.

So i decide to display both buttons and use a function to hide one, the "request quote" button on simple product. I use a part of code of this thread [Disabling Add to Cart Button for Specific WooCommerce Products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330032/disabling-add-to-cart-button-for-specific-woocommerce-products)

Initialy the code hide the add to cart button but i transform it on this :

```
// Add a custom field in the Product data's General tab (for simple products).
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_general_product_data_custom_field' );
function add_general_product_data_custom_field() {
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( // Checkbox.
        'id'            => '_not_ready_to_quote',
        'label'         => __( 'No quote', 'woocommerce' ),
        'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_simple',
    ) );
}

// Save custom field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_general_product_data_custom_field', 10, 1 );
function save_general_product_data_custom_field( $product ) {
    $product->update_meta_data( '_not_ready_to_quote', isset( $_POST['_not_ready_to_quote'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no' );
}

// Make not request quote products with '_not_ready_to_quote' meta data set to "yes" (for simple products)
add_filter( 'yith_ywraq_before_print_button', 'ywraq_hide_quote_for_simple_products', 10, 2);
function ywraq_hide_quote_for_simple_products( $show, $product ) {
    return 'yes' === $product->get_meta( '_not_ready_to_quote' ) && $product->is_type('simple') ? false : $show;

}

// Change button text to "No quote" for simple products not request quote.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_request_quote_text', 'filter_product_request_quote_text', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_request_quote_text( $button_text, $product ) {
    if ( 'yes' === $product->get_meta( '_not_ready_to_quote' ) && $product->is_type('simple') ) {
        $button_text =  __( 'No quote', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $button_text;
}
```

Hope it can help someone someday !