# Disable WooCommerce Add to Cart button for a specific "Brand" Custom Field value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I have a coding problem that is just out of my capacity.

I have setup a WooCommerce store with WooCommerce Brands plugin.

I need to be able to "Close" a brand by disabling the "Add to Cart" button. I don't want it to disappear, I only want to disable the button.

I have created a custom field using Advanced Custom Fields and assigned it to the "Brands" taxonomy which is "product_brand".

**My custom field is:** close_store
**Type:** Checkbox
**Options:** Open (Default value) | Closed

When I go to edit a "Brand" I can see my custom field and when I select "Closed" I need a function to then disable the "Add to Cart" buttons.

Is there anyone who can help with this ?

**Possible Cross Reference:**
[Disabling Add to Cart Button for Specific WooCommerce Products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330032/disabling-add-to-cart-button-for-specific-woocommerce-products/55330331#55330331)

The above looks to do a similar thing but uses "Labels" as the closing criteria and not a custom field. There may be some cross reference here in terms of how the function may need to work.

Hope this helps!

--------------------------------->

**UPDATE** - Possible Help

Provided by ACF Theme Code Pro Plugin

Taxonomy Term Variables

```
<?php
// Define taxonomy prefix eg. 'category'
// Use 'term' for all taxonomies
$taxonomy_prefix = 'product_brand';

// Define term ID
// Replace NULL with ID of term to be queried eg '123' 
$term_id = NULL;

// Example: Get the term ID in a term archive template 
// $term_id = get_queried_object_id();

// Define prefixed term ID
$term_id_prefixed = $taxonomy_prefix .'_'. $term_id;
?>



<?php $close_store_checked_values = get_field( 'close_store', $term_id_prefixed ); ?>
<?php if ( $close_store_checked_values ) : ?>
    <?php foreach ( $close_store_checked_values as $close_store_value ): ?>
        <?php echo esc_html( $close_store_value ); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: For info: WooCommerce Brands plugin taxonomy for product brands is not "Brands" but "product_brand"… So something is wrong in your question related to taxonomy ACF custom fields

Comment: Hello, I wouldn't say it was wrong. I was simply stating I was using the "Brands" plugin which creates the "Brands" taxonomy. I should maybe have provided the slug when referencing this within a function. I have updated my question.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have sent you a DM :)