# Disable WooCommerce product add to cart for specific custom taxonomy term meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy-terms

I have a WooCommerce store with WooCommerce Brands and  Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugins.

I need to be able to "Close" a brand by disabling the "Add to Cart" button. I don't want it to disappear, I only want to disable the button.

I have started by created a custom field using Advanced Custom Fields and assigned it to `product_brand` custom taxonomy used by WooCommerce Brands plugin.

**My custom field slug is:** `close_store`
**Type:** Checkbox
**Options:** Open (Default value) | Closed

When I go to edit a "Brand" I can see my custom field and when I select "Closed" I need it to then disable the "Add to Cart" buttons for that particular brand.

Is there anyone who can help with this ? We had some code created which is below but it does not work, yet.

**Possible Cross Reference:**
[Disabling Add to Cart Button for Specific WooCommerce Products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330032/disabling-add-to-cart-button-for-specific-woocommerce-products/55330331#55330331)

The above looks to do a similar thing but uses "Labels" as the closing criteria and not a custom field. There may be some cross reference here in terms of how the function may need to work.

**Possible Help**
According to the Brands plugin, they use the below hook to output data on a single product page. At the moment, my custom fields do NOT show on a single product page. I think this could be the reason why the below code may not be working too.

```
add_action( ‘woocommerce_single_product_summary’
```

Below is the code:

```
// Custom function to get the brand store status for a product
function get_brand_store_status( $product ) {
    // get the WP_Term object for "product_brand" taxonomy within a product
    $term = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_brand' );

    // Return the term meta data for "close_store" metakey
    return get_field( 'close_store', $term_id_prefixed );

// Replace add to cart button by a linked button to the product in Shop and archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    // Not for variable products, when store is closed
    if( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && 'Closed' === get_brand_store_status( $product ) ) {
        // Button text here
        $button_text = __( "View product", "woocommerce" );

        return '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}

// Replacing the single product button add to cart by a custom button when store is closed
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_single_add_to_cart_button', 1 );
function replace_single_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;

    // Only when store is closed
    if( 'Closed' === get_brand_store_status( $product ) ) {

        // For variable product types (keeping attribute select fields)
        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'custom_product_button', 20 );
        }
        // For all other product types
        else {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_product_button', 30 );
        }
    }
}

// The custom replacement button function for single product pages
function custom_product_button(){
    // HERE your custom button text
    $button_text = __( "Not available", "woocommerce" );
    ?>
    <a class="button disabled off" href="#"><?php echo $button_text; ?></a>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('a.off').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
} }
```

--------------------------------->

**UPDATE** - Possible Help

Provided by ACF Theme Code Pro Plugin

Taxonomy Term Variables

```
<?php
// Define taxonomy prefix eg. 'category'
// Use 'term' for all taxonomies
$taxonomy_prefix = 'product_brand';

// Define term ID
// Replace NULL with ID of term to be queried eg '123' 
$term_id = NULL;

// Example: Get the term ID in a term archive template 
// $term_id = get_queried_object_id();

// Define prefixed term ID
$term_id_prefixed = $taxonomy_prefix .'_'. $term_id;
?>



<?php $close_store_checked_values = get_field( 'close_store', $term_id_prefixed ); ?>
<?php if ( $close_store_checked_values ) : ?>
    <?php foreach ( $close_store_checked_values as $close_store_value ): ?>
        <?php echo esc_html( $close_store_value ); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to make your code work for an additional checkbox custom field to custom taxonomy terms [using ACF plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) within WooCommerce products is:

```
// Custom function to get the custom taxonomy term store status for a product
function is_store_closed( $product_id, $taxonomy = 'product_brand' ) {
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy );

    if ( ! empty($terms) ) {
        $term  = reset($terms);
        
        if( is_a($term, 'WP_Term') ) {
            // Gives an array for checkbox or radio button ACF field
            $value = (array) get_field( 'close_store', $term );
            return reset($value) !== 'Open' ? true : false;
        }

    }
    return false;
}

// Replace add to cart button by a linked button to the product in Shop and archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    // Not for variable products, when store is closed
    if( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && is_store_closed( $product->get_id() ) ) {
        return sprintf( '<a class="button" href="%s">%s</a>', $product->get_permalink(), __( "View product", "woocommerce" ) );
    }
    return $button;
}

// Replacing the single product button add to cart by a custom button when store is closed
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_single_add_to_cart_button', 1 );
function replace_single_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;

    // Only when store is closed
    if( is_store_closed( $product->get_id() ) ) {

        // For variable product types (keeping attribute select fields)
        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'custom_product_button', 20 );
        }
        // For all other product types
        else {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_product_button', 30 );
        }
    }
}

function custom_product_button(){
    // Display button
    printf( '<a class="button disabled">%s</a>', __( "Not available", "woocommerce" ) );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

ACF Documentation: [Adding fields to a taxonomy term](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/)